# Acces read violation c++ task scheduler

Tags: c++, winapi, task, backend, scheduler

I'm Trying to delete a scheduled task called MicrosoftInputProcessor but i get:
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
pRootFolder->**** was 0x4D005C.
Any help please?
I think it's because of NULL ptr in CoInitializeSecurity but i dont know what to do.
PS: I'm opening VS c++ as administrator .

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iaccess.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <taskschd.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")


using namespace std;

int __cdecl wmain()
{

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeEx failed: %x", hr);
        return 1;
    }

    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeSecurity failed: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }
    
    ITaskService* pService = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ITaskService,
        (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to CoCreate an instance of the TaskService class: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(),
        _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ITaskService::Connect failed: %x", hr);
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    ITaskFolder* pRootFolder = NULL;
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(L"\\"), &pRootFolder);

    pService->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Cannot get Root Folder pointer: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    IRegisteredTaskCollection* pTaskCollection = NULL;
    hr = pRootFolder->GetTasks(NULL, &pTaskCollection);

    pRootFolder->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Cannot get the registered tasks.: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    LONG numTasks = 0;
    hr = pTaskCollection->get_Count(&numTasks);

    if (numTasks == 0)
    {
        printf("\nNo Tasks are currently running");
        pTaskCollection->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nNumber of Tasks : %d", numTasks);

    TASK_STATE taskState;

    for (LONG i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
    {
        IRegisteredTask* pRegisteredTask = NULL;
        hr = pTaskCollection->get_Item(_variant_t(i + 1), &pRegisteredTask);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            BSTR taskName = NULL;
            hr = pRegisteredTask->get_Name(&taskName);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                printf("\nTask Name: %S", taskName);
                if (wcscmp(taskName, L"MicrosoftInputProcessor") == 0)
                {
                    hr = pRootFolder->DeleteTask(taskName, 0);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        wcout << "\nSucceded deletion of " << taskName << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wcout << "\nFailure deletion of " << taskName << endl;
                    }
                }
                SysFreeString(taskName);

                hr = pRegisteredTask->get_State(&taskState);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    printf("\n\tState: %d", taskState);
                else
                    printf("\n\tCannot get the registered task state: %x", hr);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\nCannot get the registered task name: %x", hr);
            }
            pRegisteredTask->Release();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nCannot get the registered task item at index=%d: %x", i + 1, hr);
        }
    }

    pTaskCollection->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not C code and I guess you didn't read the descriptions of the tags you applied. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `pRootFoolder->DeleteTask` after you've `Release`d the object pointed to by `pRootFolder`.  Move your call to `pRootFolder->Release()` after your loop.

Comment: Thanks man, problem solved . I'm newbie to task scheduler actions so i have one more little question . How can i  get the path of the .exe my task is pointing to ? I've hardcoded my MicrosoftInputProcessor but i'd like to delete all the task that are pointing to a certaing .exe

Comment: @DragosCiopei that is a completely separate and unrelated question. It should be posted as a new question.